# SELECT query based on optional conditions failing on NULL in target table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Test Schema:

```
create table users
(
    id int primary key identity(1,1),
    firstname varchar(50),
    lastname varchar(50)
);

insert into users (firstname, lastname) 
values ('John', 'Doe'), ('Jane', 'Doe');
```

Now we have the following table

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | John      | Doe      |
| 2  | Jane      | Doe      |
```

What I am trying to do is pass a set of optional parameters into a stored procedure and select from the table based on that. The parameter will be NULL as default to indicate that the condition is **not** required.

Now my select query for all users with the firstname 'John'

```
declare @fn varchar(50) = 'John';
declare @ln varchar(50) = NULL;

select * 
from users 
where firstname = isnull(@fn, firstname) 
  and lastname = isnull(@ln, lastname);
```

Where it fails is when a column in the target table itself is null. Then it enters into that `NULL = NULL` case and does not return that row. For eg. If I update the row with `id=1` to make the table like this

```
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
| 1  | John      | NULL     |
| 2  | Jane      | Doe      |
```

then the query just fails. I am using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
where (firstname = @fn or @fn is null) and
      (lastname = @ln or @ln is null)
```

Comment: `@rn` should be `@fn`.